# How to know if a Worker has failed being triggered/executed by the queue?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am appending workers in the queue as shown below. However, occasionally a worker won't be triggered. How can I know if a Worker did not get executed so that I can try to re-enqueue it? Maybe using the `Operation` instance returned by `enqueue()`? How to use it? If so, is it possible to have a hint of the reason of failure of triggering the Worker?

Note that I do not need to know if the Worker failed (`return Result.FAILURE`). The case I want to cover is when the Worker is not even called, which happens occasionally.

```
OneTimeWorkRequest sendMessageWorker = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SendMessageWorker.class)
        .setInputData(data)
        .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, backOffDelayInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();

Operation operation = WorkManager.getInstance()
        .beginUniqueWork(SendMessageWorker.class.getSimpleName(), ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, sendMessageWorker)
        .enqueue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND`, you´re creating a chain of work.
If you return `Result.FAILURE` in your Worker (in case of an error), all the chain of Work is cancelled. This maybe the reason why you don´t see your worker running sometimes.

One suggestion is to add a Tag or an Id to your worker and observe the status using a Livedata and the `getStatusesByTagLivedata()` or `getStatusesById()`.

You can take a look at [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83a4rYXsDs0) presented at the Android Developer Summit that covers this and other example.

Comment: I am sure it is not because of Result.FAILURE, because before returning such a result, I have error logging. Also all the logic of my worker is wrapped by a try/catch and if any error occurs I log and I can always see any error. It really seems that the worker, occasionally, is just not triggered at all by the queue (about 1 time on 100 times). I will watch the talk today! Thank you for the video

Answer (score 1):

You can observe the work manager's operation state.

```
OneTimeWorkRequest sendMessageWorker = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SendMessageWorker.class)
        .setInputData(data)
        .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, backOffDelayInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();

Operation operation = WorkManager.getInstance()
        .beginUniqueWork(SendMessageWorker.class.getSimpleName(), ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, sendMessageWorker)
        .enqueue();

operation.getState().observe(ProcessLifecycleOwner.get(), (state -> {
            if (state instanceof Operation.State.SUCCESS) {
                // Handle success
            } else if (state instanceof Operation.State.FAILURE) {
                // Handle failure
            }
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the Worker and get the state of worker by observing using method `getStatusByIdLiveData`

```
mWorkManager.getStatusByIdLiveData(yourWorkRequest.id)
        .observe(lifeCycleOwner, Observer { workStatus ->
            //here you can get the status of work
        })
```